# What does the Bible say about body art/tattos?

Tags: biblical-basis, bible, old-testament

I'm not Christian myself but I have many Christian friends who have tattoos/body art. Is this something that is forbidden in Christianity?

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE. For a quick overview, please take the [Site Tour](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour). As currently asked, your question is too broad for this site. There are many different Christian denominations, and they have differing views about tattoos. If you wanted to ask about the view of a specific denomination of Christians, that would be on-topic here. You could also try searching for "tattoo" in the search box to see what's already here. See also: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Closely related: [Are Catholics prohibited from getting their body tattooed?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/51006/are-catholics-prohibited-from-getting-their-body-tattooed)

Comment: Also related: [What is the biblical basis to either consider tattoos acceptable or not?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/14532/21576)

Answer (score 3):

The Bible mentions tattoos just once, at Leviticus 19:28, which says: “You must not put tattoo marking upon yourselves.”  This prohibition was for the nation of Israel and should not be taken to apply to the New Covenant relationship that GOD has established with Christians.
  I am not aware of any major Christian denominations that directly address tattoos nor do they prohibit them.  There are some smaller groups, however, that prohibit tattoos.
  The simple answer is that nothing in the New Covenant prohibits Christians from getting tattoos.

Comment: I'd recommend adding a little context to the citation from Leviticus, regarding who (slaves) were the tattooed ones.   This answer is a good start, but I think adding that context might help.

Comment: The LDS directly address tattoos ... https://www.lds.org/topics/tattooing?lang=eng&old=true, though I guess they aren't necessarily a major Christian denomination if you are just looking at population

Answer (score 2):

The Bible [says](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1%20Corinthians%206:19&version=TLB):

> Do you not know that your bodies are temples of the Holy Spirit, who
>   is in you, whom you have received from God?

Most tattoos are of something the person considers is important (e.g. the name of a girl friend), it is clearly not correct define the “Temple of God” in such a way.   This excludes most but not all tattoos.